# Is there a way to show all installed NuGet packages in a MVC View?

Tags: model-view-controller, nuget

I would like to inventory list of packages for a solution outside of using the console. Ideally a job perhaps that would loop through projects and store packages info into a database. And, is there a way to output contents of NuGet Console command:
`PM> Get-Package`
to View in MVC? Obviously a view is easy once this info in the database.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a Package Manager so that a list of managed packages can be viewed in a registry. As an example is to use GitLab Package Manager: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/ - at least you can view all packages in the UI and not run any commands once everything is setup properly.

To do this in Visual Studio, install "NuGet.Build" NuGet package to enable nuget command in console if not enabled already. Then configure your GitLab source, 000 - is the project id - you can find that in GitLab under Project Name display.

You can also do this in PowerShell by running "dotnet nuget" command.

```
nuget sources Add -name SOURCENAME -user USERID -password "API_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY" -source "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/000/packages/nuget/index.json"
```

Push one of the packages like this:

```
nuget push "packages\SafeNuGet.1.0.10\SafeNuGet.1.0.10.nupkg" -source SOURCENAME
```

If you CD into packages folder you may not need to specify folders otherwise you may get an error "file not found". If you know how to push * all projects please improve this answer. Thank you